# Html body changes its charset from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have html body with unicode symbols. Html body is in utf-8.
After creating message, html body changes its charset from utf-8 to iso-8895-1 and some of symbols changes too.
Original message:
[image]
Exported message:
[image]
Original html body:
[image]
Exported html body:
[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

**[ADDITION]**
There is a chunk of html body, how I import it to ES:

```
<html xmlns:reportsection="http://xslt.cortexit.com/reportsection"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>
        &quot;1.4 SP Job to Network Location ä Ä ö  Ö  ü  Ü  ß  &quot; Bericht</title><style type="text/css">
        .reportHeader { background-color: #505d6c; }...
```

P.S. This bug appears only on ES2013(win2012)

Comment: Your output is clear (Outlook) but what about the import: how were the data put into Exchange Server?

Comment: Thank you for your question! See appendix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've solved it by myself.

Problem was in MAPI property 0x3FDE (PidTagInternetCodepage). I've just erased it.